# SEDE Extend graph support

Tags: feature-request, support, data-explorer, graphs

I created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/586018/) which counts the number of post in a certain timeperiod for given tags. The result is pivoted.

I would like the graphing support to be extended to support pivoted-results of the format string, number, [number, number, ...]

The column-title would be the X-Axis, the values would be the Y-Axis.

#### Side note

It is not always clear to me

- How the creation of a query under my account
- How creating and saving revisions

work. Also I would like to be able to delete revisions.

Comment: Please stick with one question per, well, question. Your "side note" is bunch of totally unrelated questions. Anyway, "creation of a query under my account" is done when you're logged in. Every time you change something and execute, a new revision is made. We can't delete queries or revisions. If you don't want others to see your experiments and possible mistakes, don't log in.