# Would like a histogram option added to Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Looking at the Help link on Stack Exchange Data explorer, I don't see any way to create a horizontally scrollable histogram. I want to develop queries that could let's say, show how many votes I got for answers for various tags at various points along a time scale for example, or even for specific questions, and the x vs. y curve graph doesn't accommodate that.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287509/sede-extend-graph-support and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278966/how-do-i-make-a-bar-chart-in-the-data-explorer/278967#278967

Answer (score 3):

You can actually accomplish quite a lot with what's there. Not histograms, but you don't need them.

Here's the one query you asked about... as a line graph (run on my Stack Overflow ID):

### [Votes per tag over time](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/626449/votes-per-tag-over-time?UserId=6083675#graph)

[image]

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT
    votes.creationdate
    ,tagname
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY tagname ORDER BY votes.creationdate)
    
FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id and VoteTypeId = 2
WHERE 
    Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
```

---

### Bar Graphs

I've got a self-answered question about making bar graphs in SEDE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278967/323179) (also linked in the comments). I updated it today, since I found a way to start each "bar" at 0:

[image: Bar Graph]

The bars here are pretty arbitrary. It's possible, with enough coding ability, to make a similar graph with each bar being a month, or a tag, or whatever.

Comment: To be fair, those are prodigious efforts and an admirable attempt to work around a glaring deficiency, but they in no way are as convenient nor have the familiar comfortable aesthetic of real bar charts or histograms. I've got decades of diverse programming experience so I don't doubt I could hack something together (now that I've seen your examples and the quality/flavor of results likely achievable), but I think having that other graph type would suit a lot of different needs a lot better.   A pie chart would also probably be really useful. Not asking for a luxury like topographical charts.